# Undefined index in php when executing sql statement

Tags: php

I am getting an error when I execute this query in php:

```
SELECT hit.timestamp, 
       hit.id, 
       config.Name, 
       hit.meter_id, 
       levels.LevelName, 
       pos.sm_pos, 
       hit.hit_value 
FROM   hit 
       INNER JOIN config 
               ON hit.id = config.id 
       INNER JOIN levels 
               ON hit.meter_id = levels.id 
       INNER JOIN POS 
               ON pos.id = hit.id 
       INNER JOIN controllers 
               ON pos.controller_id = controllers.id;
```

Problem is that I am getting undefined index on each column in my select statement except the first one. Fist one is not giving me error and it gives me data normally. Other are giving errors.

Any idea what is wrong? And what I need to change?

EDIT:
This query is used when using [DataTables](http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql) script. So fully php code is this when using this script:

```
<?php
    /*
     * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
     * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine
     * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
     */

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array( 'hit.timestamp','hit.id', 'config.Name', 'hit.meter_id','levels.LevelName','pos.sm_pos','hit.hit_value'  );

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "hit.id";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "hit 
       INNER JOIN config 
               ON hit.id = config.id 
       INNER JOIN levels 
               ON hit.meter_id = levels.id 
       INNER JOIN POS 
               ON pos.id = hit.id 
       INNER JOIN controllers 
               ON pos.controller_id = controllers.id";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "";
    $gaSql['password']   = "";
    $gaSql['db']         = "";
    $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */

    /* 
     * MySQL connection
     */
    $gaSql['link'] =  mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) or
        die( 'Could not open connection to server' );

    mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) or
        die( 'Could not select database '. $gaSql['db'] );


    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }


    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }


    /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
            }
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

This last part when outputing is using `$row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];` and I think this is where problem is as I am using table.column type in the select statement. And funny thing is that my first column from select statement is going trough and I am getting the values. And others are giving me undefined index.

Comment: Your SQL query is not directly linked to your PHP errors. Show the PHP code that gives you the undefined index errors and show us the full error messages.

Comment: It just says `Undefined index: hit.id` and then the same thing for all the columns

Comment: You forgot to paste your surrounding PHP code.

Comment: @denonth In PHP, you reference the column names via the `column_name`, not `table_name.column_name`. So you would do `$id = $row['id'];` instead of `$id = $row['hit.id'];`. If you need to select columns from multiple tables where the columns have the same name, you use `SELECT column_name AS alias` to distinguish between them in the result set. This is actually a function of MySQL no matter what the client language.

Comment: @DaveRandom Can you give me example on my code for the alias? I need to this code to work so if you know what I need to do write me an answer below

Comment: @denonth In the query above you don't need to use an alias because you are not retrieving any columns with the same name in the field list. Where you would need it is if you where selecting e.g. `config.id`, then you would need to do something like `SELECT hit.id, config.id AS config_id ...`, and in PHP the value of `config.id` would be accessible through `$row['config_id']`

Comment: @DaveRandom I am using this query for datatables here is the link to the php script which they have : http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql Now scroll down to the output area they are printing values as you said but I have tried to put alias and it is giving me an error. I need to have  table.column in the query as I am fetching data from multiple tables and a lot of table have the same name. what do you suggest when you see the php script that I am using? How to form my php to work

Comment: @denonth I have to be honest, I can't really see any correlation between the linked code and the above query. Can you edit the question with your actual code where you are having this problem?

Comment: When possible, please move extended discussions to [chat].

Comment: @DaveRandom Dave I am sorry for answering today. I have tried your code and it keeps giving me a `MySQL Error: 1054`

Comment: To all future visitors: several comments deleted, we are now discussing [this code](http://pastebin.com/HuPgcPmy). @denonth Please join me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12475/undefined-index-in-php-when-executing-sql-statement) as requested by mod, and maybe delete some of the chatty comments towards the end (everything from `sure I will do that now`). :-D

Comment: @DaveRandom Hi dave so here is the request for datetime picker: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/test.php?from=06%2F15%2F2011%2009%3A57%20AM&to=12%2F15%2F2011%2009%3A57%20AM`

Comment: Well that looks like what you want - is it still not working? I suppose the question is "can `strtotime()` make sense of those strings"? If not working, what are you getting back? Still the full unfiltered result set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been resolved by using a [modified version](http://pastebin.com/HuPgcPmy) of the DataTables example script and further [discussion on SO chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12475/undefined-index-in-php-when-executing-sql-statement).

I will give a full write up in the form of a proper answer for future visitors as soon as I have time.

---

In a nutshell:

The DataTables [sample PHP script](http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql) does not accommodate the possibility of using column aliases or MySQL function calls in its field list mechanism. This makes any query that performs JOINs or applies some form of data transformation to the results impossible to accomplish without some modification.

The modified version linked above uses regex to safely use field aliases but still does not allow for function calls, which is what was really required to produce the desired result in this instance. This has been worked around by subbing some of the transformation work out to PHP, and a few additional modifications to apply a user defined date range to the returned results.

Full details of exactly what was done and why can be seen by viewing the links above.

---

If there's one thing I have taken away from the process that is potentially useful to future visitors, it is this:

> **If you need anything more than the very simplest query for use with DataTables, you'd best make damn sure you understand every last line of the back end code and how it interfaces with the front end.**
>
> The supplied example scripts do make a good starting point but they are by no means exhaustive in terms of their capabilities, and you need to be prepared to modify or even completely rewrite them in order to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Dave do you have a minute? Meet me in the old chat room.

Comment: Dave can you help me and give me an idea how can I do this operation so I can put it in the rows for certain column. I have tried this in the sql and it is working but not in this script. Can you give me idea of how to do it in the php or you can change regex? `(wa_a.DTI / 100) * wa_b.INCR_PERCENT `

Comment: @denonth If you can get the raw data for the columns `wa_a.DTI` and `wa_b.INCR_PERCENT` by specifying them in the field list then yes, no problem, you can just do it in the final `while` loop - but I'm starting to think that a complete rewrite of the script might be in order to accomplish what you want. The bit that would need re-writing would be the upper part of the script that builds the query, I don't have time to look at it properly now (or, realistically, for the next week or so - I am very busy on a project at work) but I will help you if you are still unable to do it by then.

Comment: I'm can't really tell you where to go with it at the moment, for one thing because the table aliases `wa_a` and `wa_b` don't exist in the above query, so I don't know how they relate to the rest of the data.

Comment: I figure it out. Thank you anyway